# applying functions to multiple dataframe columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with one column (R) and 30 columns (I 1: 1 30).

I have wrote a function that calls the 'R' and 'I 1' as x_data and y_data as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filepath, index_col = None)

x_data = df1['R']
y_data = df1['I 1']

def find_peaks(grad):
    peaks=[]                                    
    i = 0                                        
    while i < len(grad[:-1]):                   
        if grad[i] > 0:                         
            start = i                           
            peak_index = find_peak(start, grad) 
            end = find_end(peak_index, grad)    
            area = np.trapz(y_data[start:end], x_data[start:end]) 
            peaks.append((x_data[peak_index], y_data[peak_index], area))  
            i = end - 1                  
        else:
            i+=1                              
    return peaks
```

This function finds peaks and returns their peak areas.

How could I run this for 30 different 'I's as y_data but with the same 'R' as x_data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `x_data` and `y_data` as parameters to the function, and then loop from 1 to 30 , applying the function to each `I <num` column>. Example -

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filepath, index_col = None)

def find_peaks(grad, x_data, y_data):
    ...
    ...

for i in range(1,31):
    result = find_peaks(grad,df1['R'], df1['I {}'.format(i)])
    #Do whatever you want with the result
```

Comment: Where are you printing it?

Comment: I'm trying to convert the result to a csv file. Print works but I can't save the result as np.savetxt... it only returns one set of data. strange =/

Comment: try adding it to a list, and then after the loop use savetxt ?

Comment: The function 'find_peaks' already creates a list called peaks. So I don't think creating a list of lists is possible?

Comment: creating a list of lists is also possible, but if it creates a list, and you are using `np.savetxt` . I guess it will overwrite previous writes (unless you give it a file  handle which you openned using `a` mode).

Comment: Is it possible to just add all lists to a dataframe?

Comment: I believe so. You can again create a list of lists, and the create a dataframe from it